# tensorflow program got stuck in variables

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am studying Tensorflow and got some problems. I want to minimize loss function when i am trying to approximate `2x+2z-3t=y` (to get a,b,c values where a=2,b=2,c=-3) but it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

This is my output:

```
a: [ 0.51013279] b: [ 0.51013279] c: [ 1.00953674] loss: 2.72952e+10
```

I need a:2 b:2 c:-3 and loss close to 0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.Variable([1], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([1], dtype=tf.float32)
c = tf.Variable([0], dtype=tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
linear_model = a * x + b * z + c * t
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - y))  # sum of the squares

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
 train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

x_train = np.arange(0, 5000, 1)
z_train = np.arange(0, 10000, 2)
t_train = np.arange(0, 5000, 1)
y_train = list(map(lambda x, z, t: 2 * x + 2 * z - 3 * t, x_train, z_train, 
t_train))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(10000):
sess.run(train, {x: x_train, z: z_train, t: t_train, y: y_train})

curr_a, curr_b, curr_c, curr_loss = sess.run([a, b, c, loss], {x: x_train, 
z: z_train, t: t_train, y: y_train})
print("a: %s b: %s c: %s loss: %s" % (curr_a, curr_b, curr_c, curr_loss))
```

I changed Maxim's code a bit to see values of a,b,c like this:

```
_, loss_val, curr_a, curr_b, curr_c, model_val = sess.run([optimizer, 
loss,a, b, c, linear model],           {x: x_train, z: z_train, t: t_train, 
y: y_train})
```

So my output is:

10 2.04454e-11 1.83333 0.666667 -0.166667

20 2.04454e-11 1.83333 0.666667 -0.166667

30 2.04454e-11 1.83333 0.666667 -0.166667

I expected a=2,b=2,c=-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, there is no single solution, so the optimizer can converge to any one of local minima. The exact value greatly depends on initialization of your variables.

Short answer concerning your bug: **be careful with the learning rate**. Checkout my version of your code:

```
a = tf.Variable(2, dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.float32)
c = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
z = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
t = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)

linear_model = a * x + b * z + c * t
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(linear_model - y))  # sum of the squares
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(loss)

n = 50
x_train = np.arange(0, n, 1).reshape([-1, 1])
z_train = np.arange(0, 2*n, 2).reshape([-1, 1])
t_train = np.arange(0, n, 1).reshape([-1, 1])
y_train = np.array(map(lambda x, z, t: 2 * x + 2 * z - 3 * t, x_train, z_train, t_train)).reshape([-1, 1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  for i in range(101):
    _, loss_val = sess.run([optimizer, loss], {x: x_train, z: z_train, t: t_train, y: y_train})
    if i % 10 == 0:
      a_val, b_val, c_val = sess.run([a, b, c])
      print('iteration %2i, loss=%f a=%.5f b=%.5f c=%.5f' % (i, loss_val, a_val, b_val, c_val))
```

If you run it, you'll notice that it converges very fast - in less than 10 iterations. However, if you increase the training size `n` from `50` to `75`, the model is going to diverge. But decreasing the learning rate `0.00001` will make it converge again, though not so fast as before. The more data you push to the optimizer, the more important an appropriate learning rate becomes.

You've tried `5000` training size: I can't even imaging how small the learning rate should be to process that many points at once correctly.

Comment: but values are not close to expected a=2,b=2 ,c=-3
I thought we need to get something like this

Comment: @СтаниславКитаев see my answer: there are many local minima. The found a, b, c fit the data almost perfectly. Initialize them differently and you'll get another solution.

Comment: May you answer one more question?
Can i modify this function by adding powers to variables (like x^2...)?

Comment: @СтаниславКитаев Sure, tf supports pow function - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pow. The optimization will still work.